# Android retrofit unexpected value of 'canceled' flag in 'onFailure()' after cancelling all Requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using the latest version of Retrofit. I am performing multiple requests in an activity and in `onDestroy` method, i.e. when the activity ends, I wish to terminate all the pending requests and hence I am calling `okHttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll()`.

The `onFailure` method of the request is handled in this manner :-

```
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<APIResponseClass> call, Throwable t) {

            if (call != null && !call.isCanceled()) {
                // Call is not cancelled, Handle network failure

                onNetworkFailure(call, t);

            } else if (call != null && call.isCanceled()){

                // Call is CANCELLED. IGNORE THIS SINCE IT WAS CANCELLED.

            }
        }
```

Problem is, I'm receiving an unexpected behavior in onFailure method. Despite the call being cancelled through `okHttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll()` , the **canceled** flag is received as `false`, which should have been `true`, i.e. `call.isCancelled()` should have been `true`.

However, the variable `Throwable t` surprisingly is sending the cause as **java.io.IOException: Canceled** and the detailMessage as **Canceled** . I have added the Screenshot of my debugger...

[image]

**My question is, if the cause of the exception is determined as the cancellation of the request, why isn't the canceled flag displaying proper result??**

I have been [referring to this link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests) for cancelling ongoing retrofit requests...

Please Help.

Comment: Could this be a bug in the Retrofit library? Or am I missing something? From the link given here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests  they are also using the method `call.isCanceled()` for this purpose. If it is a bug, can I raise an issue in their github repository?? I need your suggestions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that I hate answering my questions, since nobody answered here, I am writing this in order to help others facing similar issues.

Yes, this is a bug in the Retrofit Library. Since nobody responded in StackOverflow, I raised the same query in the official Retrofit Github repository.
You can find the link to the issue over here.
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2076

This is expected to be fixed in the Retrofit version v2.2.